Null reference exception when adding bodies to a list
So, for conversational clarity/brevity, I have 3 sphere gameobjects, each with their own Rigidbody component. They all have a tag of 'body'. The 3 spheres have progressively larger masses.

body1 mass: 100000
body2 mass: 10000
body3 mass: 1000

So, what I am seeking to do is to assign a gravitational force to each object by using the Newtonian formula for gravitational force.

Perhaps that's a bit too much for the moment. The main issue I am seeking to address is that I have this code which seeks to assign a gravitational force to each body;
void Start() {
  selfBodyName = this.name;
  selfMass = GameObject.Find(selfBodyName).GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass;
  bodies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("body");

  // Trying to fill array of each body's rigidbody reference.
  for(int i = 0; i < bodies.Length; i++) {
    bodiesRb[i] = bodies[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  }
}

Problem I am encountering is that when the for loop runs, it gives me the infamous "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to the instance of an object."
So, I just would like an extra set of eyes to tell me if I have overlooked something. Known facts:

I know that the bodies array is populated and its length = 3.
Each sphere gameobject has a rigidbody component with the respective masses set.

So, what am I overlooking here?

@Kevin Actually, in this case they don't even need to do that. They could just use selfMass = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass;

First, GameObject.Find(selfBodyName) is completely unnecessary and has a high performance cost. You can just use this.gameObject.
You are referring to a variable named bodiesRb (presumably a list or array), but the code that you've shared doesn't show you initializing bodiesRb. It's likely that bodiesRb is null.
Note that this approach will not pick up any new bodies that are added to the scene after Start() is called. You're also having to create a separate list of Rigidbodies in the scene for each object with this script. In the long run, you should consider having a single component manage the gravity for all active Rigidbodies in the scene.
public class GravityManager : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<Rigidbody> rigidbodies = new List<Rigidbody>(10);

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rigidbodies.Count - 1; i++) {
            Rigidbody rb1 = rigidbodies[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < rigidbodies.Count; j++) {
                Rigidbody rb2 = rigidbodies[j];
                ApplyGravityBetween(rb1, rb2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddRigidbody(Rigidbody rb) {
        Assert.IsFalse(rigidbodies.Contains(rb), $"Rigidbody {rb} has been added to the list multiple times");
        rigidbodies.Add(rb);
    }

    public bool RemoveRigidbody(Rigidbody rb) {
        return rigidbodies.Remove(rb);
    }

    private void ApplyGravityBetween(Rigidbody rb1, Rigidbody rb2) {
        // Put gravity logic here
    }
}
```


Thanks for all the insight! I thought doing everything from a single script would have had more performance issues, but that's why I asked here as I am still trying to get my game dev feet wet. Asa 30 yr PHP programmer, this has a bit of a learning curve.

As for my uninitialized array...I thought that the iterations in the for loop would get the rigidbody from the bodies array and then get the rigidbody component and thus initialize the array elements in bodiesRb. So, I always need to initialize any declared variables before I can use them?

@Skittles Arrays and lists in C# are objects, which do not exist until you create them using the new keyword; for example, List<Rigidbody> bodiesRb = new List<Rigidbody>(). If you are unfamiliar with this concept, you should take some time to learn the basics of working with C#, as it functions very differently than PHP.

About the first paragraph: Actually, in this case they don't even need to access this.gameObject. They could just use selfMass = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass;

@Philipp Yes, I just wanted to clearly indicate that GameObject.Find(this.name) is a very bad approach.

@Skittles If the answer is helpful, please don't forget to upvote or mark it as the correct answer.
